# How is a std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray message published via CLI?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see how a std_msgs/msg/Byte message is published via CLI, in fact, there are two ways to do this. (see https://answers.ros.org/question/375231/ros2-foxy-how-to-publish-byte-message-from-commandline/)

And I know how other MultiArray messages are published via CLI. (see https://answers.ros.org/question/189073/rostopic-pub-multiarray/?answer=189097#post-id-189097)

But how do you do that for a std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray?
I have tried:

```bash
ros2 topic pub -1 /whatever std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray "{data: [{3}, {4}]}"
```

and

```bash
ros2 topic pub -1 /whatever std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray "{data: [0x03, 0x04]}"
```

But both comes back with:

```
Failed to populate field: The 'data' field must be a set or sequence and each value of type 'bytes'
```

Other info:

- Ubuntu 20
- galactic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406242/how-is-a-std_msgs/msg/bytemultiarray-message-published-via-cli?/) by [Cadmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/81960/cadmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-09-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2022-09-10**:
Trying all the usual patterns I could think of, I similarly wasn't able to get this to work from the CLI, so perhaps its a bug, and it may merit a Github issue (or perhaps I wasn't creative enough with my syntax).

As an aside, please note the deprecation warning:

> [This was originally provided as an example message. It is deprecated as of Foxy. It is recommended to create your own semantically meaningful message.](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray.html)

**Comment by [Cadmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/81960/cadmus/) on 2022-09-12**:
I am using `std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray` because its something that everyone can try. The actual thing I'm trying to do is to pub a custom message with a `byte[]` field

**Comment by [Cadmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/81960/cadmus/) on 2022-09-12**:
Issue raised at https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Confirmed that there was no way of doing this. PR to fix issue is here: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_python/pull/184

It appears that in the future we will be able to do:

`ros2 topic pub -1 /whatever std_msgs/msg/ByteMultiArray "{data: [1, 2, 3]}"`

---

Originally posted by [Cadmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/81960/cadmus/) with karma: 25 on 2022-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1